# Erro ao emular App em Samsung

Tags: firebase, listview, emulador

Peço desculpas se este erro já apareceu, mas não consegui resolvê-lo no meu app e as respostas anteriores não me surtiram efeito.
Estou desenvolvendo uma `activity` que mostre em uma `ListVew` os itens cadastrados em uma tabela específica do firebase. 
A ideia é futuramente, inserir um filtro para poder pesquisar dados dentro desta tabela.

Até o momento, ocorre o erro abaixo, ao emular (o app abre e executa, mas não mostra minha `ListView`):

> D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
>   E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
>                               motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3a9482a5
>   D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none

**Minha Activity Padaria (onde deve exibir a `ListView`):**

```
package e.servidor.myapplication.Produtos;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import e.servidor.myapplication.R;

public class Padaria extends AppCompatActivity {

    Firebase objetoRef;
    ListView minhaListPadaria;
    ArrayList<String> minhaLVpadaria = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_padaria );

        Firebase.setAndroidContext( this );

        minhaListPadaria = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.LV_padaria );
        objetoRef = new Firebase( "https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/projeto-eb1cf/database/projeto-eb1cf/data" );

        Firebase novaRef = objetoRef.child( "padaria" );

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, minhaLVpadaria );
        minhaListPadaria.setAdapter( adaptador );

        novaRef.addChildEventListener( new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue( String.class );
                minhaLVpadaria.add( message );
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Podem me ajudar?
Os modelos dos smartphones são: *Samgung E7* e *Samsung One.*

Comment: Qual é a versão do Firebase que você está usando?

Comment: Você parece ter a URL errada. Devia ser: `objetoRef = new Firebase( "https://projeto-eb1cf.firebaseio.com" );`

Comment: Olá. O comando na estrutura acima aparece permission denied. Com o link que coloquei, a conexão com a tabela ocorre mas retorna o erro (que acredito eu ser da pilha).

Comment: Vá para a sua consola do Firebase, abra a sua database. Você verá uma aba chamada "rules". Experimente colocar as rules públicas (`read: true` e `write: true`)

Comment: Isso já foi testado. Infelizmente, o rules já está com estas permissões.